# How to prepend a parameter in Swagger UI

Tags: api, format, swagger

I like apigee's approach to specifying the return format.  Is it possible to implement this approach in Swagger UI?

```
For search or for any of the action oriented (non-resource) responses, you can prepend with the format as follows: 

/search.xml?q=fluffy+fur
```

This example would return all search results for "fluffy fur" in xml format.

Answer (score 0):

this isn't possible in the default swagger-ui project.  You'd have to fork & modify the source code on your own to do this.